# Use of comma between subject and verb

Tags: uso-de-palabras

In William Strunk's Elements of Style, it is recommended that commas shouldn't be used after coordinating conjunctions that are followed by parenthetical elements:

> The Red Sox were leading the league at the end of May, but of course,
>   they always do well in the spring. (no comma after *but*)

Does this recommendation holds for Spanish? For example, is the following sentence incorrect?

> Universidad Católica fue puntero toda la liga, pero, por supuesto, salieron segundos.

Comment: The reason I dislike many style guides is they don't make much sense. In English, there's a clear difference between "..., but of course, ..." and "..., but, of course, ..." (the extra pause means that, in American English, for instance, the *t* in *but* will be voiceless and aspirated, whereas without, it turns into a voiced alveolar flap). In general, Spanish makes much less use of commas than English.

Comment: Does this phonetic difference translates into a semantic difference? Since this recommendation holds just for written English I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, there are two rules to combine:

- Always write a comma before an adversative conjunction (such as *pero*)
- All constructions meaning *of course* (such as *por supuesto*, *naturalmente*, *desde luego*...) must be surrounded by commas

You put these two norms together and get the correct punctuation, which is the one you write in your question:

> Universidad Católica fue puntero toda la liga, pero, por supuesto,
>   salieron segundos.

There is a concordance error in this sentence, but that's a different thing.

Ommitting the commas can lead to a different meaning in some sentences using these elements. For instance:

> El gato es, naturalmente, un carnívoro, pero puede subsistir con una
>   dieta omnívora.

This means: *The cat is, of course, a carnivore, but it can subsist on an omnivorous diet*.

On the other hand:

> El gato es naturalmente un carnívoro, pero puede subsistir con una
>   dieta omnívora.

This means: *The cat is a carnivore by nature, but it can subsist on an omnivorous diet*.

Comment: By a concordance error you mean: "Universidad Católica fue puntero"? That would be the case if you were talking about the university ("la universidad"), but it refers to a soccer team ("el equipo"), so it is actually masculine.

Comment: I mean that, for the same subject (*Universidad Católica*), they use first a singular verb (*fue*) and then a plural (*salieron*). It can be one or the other, but not both. In fact, in correct Spanish, collective names should use the singular, so *salieron* is incorrect.